# How to add and subtract hours in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I want to add 24 format hours then result would be either 24 format or 12 format hours as per my requirement I will use two functions

This is my example

add ('08:05'+'02:00') result is 10:05

now again I want to convert the above result into 12 hour format so as per my result it would be 10:05 AM or 10:05

Comment: You need to be *very* wary here. There's only one datatype in 2005 to support datetime values and that's `datetime`. Even on 2008, where `datetime2` and `time` exist - in all 3 cases, the `time` is a *time of day*, not a *span of time*. Those are actually two distinct concepts. Adding two *times of day* together doesn't make a great deal of sense, and you'll run into problems if you overflow 24 hours. It would be better to work in a language (e.g. C#) that has first class support for a `TimeSpan` type.

Answer (score 3):

You may use the `DateAdd` function to do this, e.g.`Dateadd(hour,2, @yourTime)`.
To display the result, you can use the  `convert` function. The `convert` function has many format options, so pick the one that suits your needs (I guess '0' would be ok).

Example:

```
select convert(varchar, dateadd(hour,2,myTimeColumn),0) as PlusTwoHours 
 from myTable.
```

Hint: Avoid formatting in SQL. I would suggest removing the `convert` part and do the formatting in your application (report engine, excel or whatever).

Comment: the time is not the fixed one it will come from database it is dynamic

Comment: where is the difference? I will add an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @TimeValueA as DateTime
DECLARE @TimeIncrementHours as int

SET @TimeValueA = '10:05:000'

SET @TimeIncrementHours  = 2


SELECT dateadd(hour,@TimeIncrementHours, @TimeValueA)
```

To Check and see if the time is 12 hour or 24 hour use the CONVERT function to a varchar like this:

FOR 24 hr

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, dateadd(hour,@TimeIncrementHours, @TimeValueA),108)
```

OR 12 hr

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(20), dateadd(hour,@TimeIncrementHours, @TimeValueA),100)
```

IN the Case where you want to add two DateTime's

> SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '10:00:000') + CONVERT(datetime, '2:10:000')

Comment: SET @TimeIncrementHours  = 2 here the time is '02:10:00' hrs and minutes both, so how can I add this to the '10:05:00'